# Getting double boundary from cadastral map with edge detector

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image]

I was trying to get cadastral map boundary by applying canny edge detector.But it identify two outter lines .But i need one central line how can i get it in python/opencv?

[image]

I have tried this one

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
img_gray = cv2.imread('ainta.tiff')

sigma = 2
threshold1=30
threshold2=60

img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray,(5,5),sigmaX=sigma,sigmaY=sigma)
res = cv2.Canny(img_blur,threshold1=threshold1,threshold2=threshold2)
cv2.imshow("Canny", res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: both pics are identical. did you mean to upload two different ones? why do you not show us the source data?

Comment: An edge detector detects edges—transition from one intensity to another. So a line has two edges. If you don’t want to detect edges, don’t use an edge detector. You probably want to look for a line detector.

Comment: Please post your input image